# Erro org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jpa, tomcat

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em *JSF 2 (Mojarra 2.1.1), JPA 2.0 (Hibernate 4.2.3), Apache Tomcat 7.0.47 e JDK 7u79* e está aparecendo essa mensagem de erro:

> ContextListener:
>   attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache',
>   'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@18ad735').